# Rails 3.1 including style sheet, browser isn't using it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, muse

My team hacked together some style sheets using Adobe Muse.

I've included those in my `assets` folder and am able to serve them just fine.

application.css:

```
/*

 *= require_self
 *= require "site_global"
 *= require "frontpage"

*/
```

What confuses me is that in chrome debugger I see that the resources load
It does not however render the stylesheet for the associated divs.

When I inspect element for the poorly displayed `<div>` tags it shows some of the elements from `site_global.css` but not from `frontpage.css`

Running on little sleep, demo this afternoon.
Might just need a fresh set of eyes.

---

**EDIT**

Adding my `application.html.erb` header

```
  <head>
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "StarterTribe" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
```

Comment: $ bundle exec rake assets:precompile

tried it, no visible effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference, but does it do anything different if you remove the quotes around them?

And I'm assuming you have this in your application layout:

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

If it's order that is important, make sure you specify the correct order in the application.css file. You can even put some items "above" `*= require_self` if necessary.

I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Trying to rearrange ordering now.

Tried earlier and couldn't make a visible difference.

Tried removing some portions, still not displaying `frontpage.css` formatting.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your page is actually using the classes that are defined in `frontpage.css`? This is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Although this won't really help posterity, but we ended up dropping the adobe based mockup and using 960.gs instead.

Comment: Glad you figured something out. :)